# Boto3 script giving me an error with change_resource_record_sets

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, amazon-route53

I am receiving an error saying this:

```
An error occurred (InvalidChangeBatch) when calling the ChangeResourceRecordSets operation: [RRSet with DNS name foo.navy.bar.net. is not permitted in zone navy.bar.net.]
```

My code is as such:

```
for up in range(len(name)) and range(len(value)):
    try:
        Route53.change_resource_record_sets(
            HostedZoneId = "888444GASFASDF333",
            ChangeBatch = {
                'Changes': [
                    {
                        'Action': 'UPSERT',
                        'ResourceRecordSet': {
                            'Name': name[up]+".",
                            'Type': 'A',
                            'ResourceRecords': [
                                {
                                    'Value': value[up]
                                }
                            ],
                            'TTL': 60
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception while updating Route53 record")
        print(e)
```

My data was originally Dictionary but then parsed to two separate Lists Arrays. The "Name" and "Value" (IP) is done like so:

```
name = []
value = []
items = route53_ip_update.items()
for item in items:
    name.append(item[0]), value.append(item[1])
```

I looked online and I found a discussion saying you must append a "." (period) at the end of "Name". I tried that and still no update is being done just this error with each DNS record.

I believe my main issue is how DNS and IPs are separated into "Name" and "Value": `foo.navy.bar.net'` and `'33.22.1.55'`

If you need more information please let me know. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you confident that `for up in range(len(name)) and range(len(value))` is correct? It does not seem right to me.

Comment: I will give it another check tomorrow.

Comment: After testing for loop with `print(name[up)` and `print(value[up])` I do get the desired variables. I am thinking once it hits `ChangeBatch` that is where it begins to have problems. I'll continue to test this area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved my question. The answer to my question is the Zone ID was incorrect. The Zone ID was targeting a different Zone when it should have been another.